# B2C: Add an external Active Directory as an Identity provider

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

I have a working B2C Tenant that authenticates a MSAL mobile application as well as a web portal. It currently just has 1 identity provider which is 'Local Account'. I also have a separate enterprise Active Directory instance the rest of my organization uses and we want to incorporate that separate AD instance as an identity provider for our B2C Tenant. I see how to add other identity providers such as Google/FB but I was wondering if it's possible to add the external AD instance as a 'New OpenID Connect provider'? I've been trying to find documentation on whether or not this is possible but I'm a bit lost in the sauce. Thanks for any tips!

Comment: You are correct . we can add single tenant/multi tenant AAD as an identity provider in your B2C tenant. Single tenant documentation :  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-single-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow 
Multi tenant : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/identity-provider-azure-ad-multi-tenant?pivots=b2c-user-flow

Answer (score 0):

Active Directory is just a repository that contains user information.

It does not have an Identity framework.

The easiest solution would be to install ADFS on top of this AD and then use OIDC to connect the two.

The harder way is to write a bridge that talks to AD via LDAP on one side and implements OIDC on the other. I don't know of any software that does this.

The other option is to use a third-party IDP.

e.g. Auth0 has an AD/LDAP Connector that will talk to AD and also implements OIDC.

Comment: We can use OpenID Connect provider to add single tenant/multi tenant AAD as identity provider for B2C.

Comment: Correct but the way the question reads it's AD not AAD.